# Abstract algebra with group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\Omega:G\to G$ be an isomorphism such that $\Omega(x)=x$ iff $x=e$ the identity element of $G$. Then prove that any element of $G$ can be reperesented as $g=x^{-1}\Omega(x)$ where $g$ belongs to the group $G$.

Comment: I know it was edited by quapka but is Is g=x-1Ω(x) supposed to read $g = x^{-1}\Omega(x)$ or $g = x - 1\Omega(x)$ because the latter looks like it's mixing of multiplicative and additive notation which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I wonder why so many students just can't write clearly...there are parentheses at least!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $x^{-1}\Omega(x)=y^{-1}\Omega(y)$ then $(xy^{-1})^{-1}\Omega(xy^{-1})=e$